# Range of ports infinispan accepts by default: replication timeout happens due to port blocking

Tags: java, caching, jboss, replication, infinispan

I came across with this issue, where infinispan cache replication time outs.

Here is the error log I got. Seems this ports got blocked, and hence time outs.
"Replication timeout for blx25ao03-38795"

So what is the default range of ports that infinispan supports or is it possible to change 
the range of ports ?

```
org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Replication timeout for blx25ao03-38795
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.invokeRemotely(JGroupsTransport.java:421)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.invokeRemotely(RpcManagerImpl.java:100)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.invokeRemotely(RpcManagerImpl.java:124)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.invokeRemotely(RpcManagerImpl.java:229)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.invokeRemotely(RpcManagerImpl.java:217)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.broadcastRpcCommand(RpcManagerImpl.java:199)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.broadcastRpcCommand(RpcManagerImpl.java:193)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.ReplicationInterceptor.handleCrudMethod(ReplicationInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.ReplicationInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(ReplicationInterceptor.java:78)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:76)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.LockingInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(LockingInterceptor.java:198)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:76)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:132)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:57)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:76)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.enlistWriteAndInvokeNext(TxInterceptor.java:183)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(TxInterceptor.java:132)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:76)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:118)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross posted to https://community.jboss.org/message/758177#758177 - help is already provided in the JBoss forums.